# perform SQL injection and patch it

Tags: sql, sql-injection

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM  Reg_Stud WHERE Username='$var1' AND RegID=$var2 ";
```

this is the code...

i tried the input

Username =anything' OR 'x'='x

ID       =12 or 1=1

no sign of sql injection...but when i just give the 1st argument and end it by commenting the rest...it gives sql error i.e anything' OR 'x'='x;--

Comment: You should use a prepared statement...

Comment: @KennyTM I think this is a homework assignment or an attempt to learn.

Answer (score 3):

> perform SQL injection and patch it

You can use [SQL Inject Me Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7597/) which has huge number of patterns it tests with :)

> SQL Injection vulnerabilites can cause
>   a lot of damage to a web application.
>   A malicious user can possibly view
>   records, delete records, drop tables
>   or gain access to your server. SQL
>   Inject-Me is Firefox Extension used to
>   test for SQL Injection vulnerabilities

To be on the safe side, you should use **[Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

You have following conditions: `Username==anything OR x=x AND RegID=12`, in boolean:
`false OR true AND false`. Apparently MySQL evaluates this entire expression as false (`(false OR true) AND false`).

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set the username to `x' or 1=1--`

Comment: Query failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' AND RegID=' at line 1

Comment: @Vinod K, ah, I just checked the syntax for comments in the mysql manual. You need to put a space after `--`. Try that. This should comment out the rest of the line and return data for all students. It would also make the value $var2 unimportant as it forms part of the comment.

Comment: Query failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1...